# Excel count distinct values in a date range by values

Tags: excel

```
Description | Invoice No | Invoice Date
Company A | INV 1 | 3/1/2017
Company A | INV 2 | 3/1/2017
Company A | INV 3 | 3/1/2017
Company B | INV A | 3/1/2017
Company B | INV A | 3/1/2017
Company B | INV B | 3/1/2017
Company C | INV A | 2/1/2017
Company C | INV B | 3/1/2017
Company C | INV C | 3/1/2017
```

I need to calculate the distinct count of a particular company's number of invoice per month based on the table.

Company A = 3

Company B = 2

Company C = 2 for March, 1 for February

The best I came out with was

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(C:C>="3/1/2017",IF(Dates<"4/1/2017",IF(A:A="Company A",IF(B:B<>"",MATCH(B:B,B:B,0)))),ROW(B:B)-MIN(ROW(B:B))+1),1),0))
```

Used with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: Cant you use the [countif](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) function?

Comment: I cant use countif if i want to get the distinct values. Example for Company B i would want to return 2 instead of 3 as there is a duplicate of INV A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, limit your range reference within the formula otherwise the formula will have to calculate for the whole columns inside each IF block and Row() function.

Try these **Array Formulas** which are confirmed with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

**For March:**

Company A:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10="Company A",IF(MONTH(C2:C10)=3,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

Company B:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10="Company B",IF(MONTH(C2:C10)=3,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

Company C:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10="Company C",IF(MONTH(C2:C10)=3,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

**For February:**

Company A:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10="Company A",IF(MONTH(C2:C10)=2,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

Company B:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10="Company B",IF(MONTH(C2:C10)=2,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

Company C:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10="Company C",IF(MONTH(C2:C10)=2,MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

Also instead of hard coding the company and month criteria, have two criteria cells on the sheet and refer them in the formula so that if you change the criteria in the criteria cells, the formula will be updated automatically.

For month criteria you can check the month names instead of month number as used in the above formulas like this...

For Company A / March criteria

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A10="Company A",IF(TEXT(C2:C10,"mmm")="Mar",MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))),ROW(B2:B10)-ROW(B2)+1)>0))
```

Comment: For setting the date range instead of using MONTH = 3, can i set it a range? There may be multiple years of March, so it will overlap. The code above works, but when I change it to change the IF to >=3/1/2017 and add another IF <4/1/2017, it doesn't work any more.

Comment: I realised that you cant use IF(C2<4/1/2017) because it divides (4/1)/2017... but it works when IF(C2>=3/1/2017). I had to change to IF(C2<DATE(2017,4,1)) instead